# How does the VertexBuffer know the type of struct inside it?

Tags: c++, c, directx

```
// Lock the vertex buffer.
hr = aVertexBuffer->Map(D3D10_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, (void**)&verticesPtr);
// Copy the data into the vertex buffer.
memcpy(verticesPtr, (void*)vertices, (sizeof(LolAnyDataStructure)* aVertexCount));
```

In this case I am using the struct LolAnyDataStructure, how would the DX know when you call IASetVertexBuffers where in the struct there texture and position are.

EDIT:

```
vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(VertexType)* aVertexCount;
vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D10_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
vertexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
```

Comment: You gave it the description when you created the buffer.

Comment: I only gave the ByteWidth, but it works if I set the offset in IASetVertexBuffers to the size of the other data. But I have to also make sure that "extra" data is added to the to the top of the Position and Texture. Is there anyway to specify that in the description inside of in the IASetVertexBuffers as an offset.

Comment: Well, initial assumption that `VertexBuffer know the type of struct inside it` was wrong. He doesn't really care =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vertex buffer is stored as bytes, you need to create an input layout that describes these bytes.

You should have something like this in your code.

```
// Define the input layout
D3D10_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
{
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
};
UINT numElements = sizeof( layout ) / sizeof( layout[0] );

// Create the input layout
D3D10_PASS_DESC PassDesc;
g_pTechnique->GetPassByIndex( 0 )->GetDesc( &PassDesc );
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateInputLayout( layout, numElements, PassDesc.pIAInputSignature,
                                      PassDesc.IAInputSignatureSize, &g_pVertexLayout );
```

In this example, it is the `layout` that describes the struct.

Comment: How do you specify with D3D10_BUFFER_DESC? I am asking this because I have additional functions inside by VertexType which causes problems when the IASetVertexBuffer tries reading the data.

Comment: @mk1 When you are creating the buffer, it just stores it as bytes. You need to create the ID3D10InputLayout which stores the layout of the bytes.

Comment: Does that mean I can skip over functions I don't need that might be in the VertexType struct I have?

Comment: @mk1 Not sure what that means, can you elaborate?

Comment: So my array of vertices is of type `VertexType` which contains **ONLY** `D3DXVECTOR3 position` and `D3DXVECTOR2 texture`. This means that I set the `stride` in `IASetVertexBuffers` to `sizeOf(VertexType)` and `offset` to 0. However, say if my VertexType contains additional functions and/or variables such as `GetType()` or `GetPositionVector()` or `HWND hwnd` (these are random) . This will throw off the alignment of the struct when `IASetVertexBuffers` is reading the data. Because its not every `sizeOf(VertexType)` aka `stride` where the position + texture are stored.

Comment: What would I do in such a case?

Comment: @mk1 You shouldn't have any functions in the `VertexType` because that throws off the alignment. If you really want to add logic, I suggest you create them outside of the class. You can create a class inside of a class. So your outter class can have the logic and your inner class is what stores the info and then you use the inner class to send to the GPU.

Comment: `You shouldn't have any functions in the VertexType` How do you know this? I am just wondering.